# ASUS P6T SE will not boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios

Just shows insert valid bootable media as if there's nothing. USB is the only boot option in BIOS. I've tried different USBs and the media works on another machine. Even with no other drives attached still the same. Same result for windows media creation tool and Ubuntu via Rufus, balena and poweriso. Tried different write modes (HDD, raw etc) and formats (fat32/ntfs).

EDIT: Sorry I mean all the other boot devices are disabled - the only option for it to boot from is the USB, which is as it should be, I just can't boot into any of the installers. When it tries to boot off the USB it's just a black screen saying "Please insert bootable media" or something similar, as if the USB is blank, though it does work in my usual machine.

Just updated bios to latest and still the same.

Comment: You state: "USB is the only boot option in BIOS. " That is **not** how BIOS should appear: https://images_bios.pugetsystems.com/52885.jpg . Is BIOS locked down, requiring a password, or have you selected **boot order**, rather than BIOS? See also https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1451033.html

Comment: Sorry I mean all the other boot devices are disabled - the only option for it to boot from is the USB, which is as it should be, I just can't boot into any of the installers. When it tries to boot off the USB it's just a black screen saying "Please insert bootable media" or something similar, as if the USB is blank, though it does work in my usual machine.

Comment: The forum thread is largely irrelevant as I understand as the Ubuntu iso should be burning the appropriate boot/efi partitions and no other drives are connected to the motherboard to interfere with the USB's partitions. I'm relatively familiar with the process and should at least be able to boot into the live USB environment... It's obviously not a UEFI board but I don't think you need a different ISO for legacy bios and it was running win 10 so the recovery usb should be detected at least.

Answer (score 0):

i have hame problem with p9t se +x5650. but with windows. one week before I install windows, but now it doesn't work(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).